# Getting a Vbscript to run in Task Scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, vbscript

I have a VBSCRIPT file that is used to backup a database once every day at a particular time, this was done using task scheduler but my problem now is this script requires you to press ok or cancel to complete the operation.

In the run command line of the Scheduler is there any switch that I can use so that it does not sit and wait for me to click ok to complete the task?

Answer (score 2):

I would think it would be the VBScript calling up the dialog (MessageBox), and not TaskScheduler. You need to
look at the script file and delete or comment out the lines that do that.